# Postgres varchar column using index inconsistently

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a query that will use a table's indexes when the input parameter is a given length, but not when the parameter is any other length.

This query will use the tables indexes correctly:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM equipment_tests et
INNER JOIN equipments e ON e.id = et.equipment_id
WHERE e.organization_id = '6c93a9b5-cde7-4660-a55a-1ba74b97fc58' 
LIMIT 100;
```

Its query plan:

```
     Limit  (cost=0.84..40.75 rows=100 width=294) (actual time=357.878..366.848 rows=100 loops=1)
   Output: et.id, et.equipment_id, et.test_id, et.equipment_config_id, et.context, et.created_at, e.id, e.organization_id, e.type, e.model, e.serial_number, e.version, e.calibration_date, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.hw_version
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.84..232724.95 rows=583224 width=294) (actual time=357.874..366.647 rows=100 loops=1)
         Output: et.id, et.equipment_id, et.test_id, et.equipment_config_id, et.context, et.created_at, e.id, e.organization_id, e.type, e.model, e.serial_number, e.version, e.calibration_date, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.hw_version
         Merge Cond: ((e.id)::text = (et.equipment_id)::text)
         ->  Index Scan using equip_id on public.equipments e  (cost=0.42..14251.87 rows=33030 width=134) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: e.id, e.organization_id, e.type, e.model, e.serial_number, e.version, e.calibration_date, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.hw_version
               Filter: ((e.organization_id)::text = '6c93a9b5-cde7-4660-a55a-1ba74b97fc58'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 5
         ->  Index Scan using equip_tests_equip_id on public.equipment_tests et  (cost=0.43..208750.41 rows=1525051 width=160) (actual time=0.005..173.042 rows=73224 loops=1)
               Output: et.id, et.equipment_id, et.test_id, et.equipment_config_id, et.context, et.created_at
 Total runtime: 366.989 ms
```

This query will not use the equipment_test.equipment_id index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *                
FROM equipment_tests et
INNER JOIN equipments e ON e.id = et.equipment_id
WHERE e.organization_id = '6c93a9b5-cde7-4660-a55a-1ba74b97fc5'
LIMIT 100;
```

Its query plan:

```
     Limit  (cost=50.06..14630.82 rows=100 width=294) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=0 loops=1)
   Output: et.id, et.equipment_id, et.test_id, et.equipment_config_id, et.context, et.created_at, e.id, e.organization_id, e.type, e.model, e.serial_number, e.version, e.calibration_date, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.hw_version
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=50.06..56623.39 rows=388 width=294) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=0 loops=1)
         Output: et.id, et.equipment_id, et.test_id, et.equipment_config_id, et.context, et.created_at, e.id, e.organization_id, e.type, e.model, e.serial_number, e.version, e.calibration_date, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.hw_version
         Hash Cond: ((et.equipment_id)::text = (e.id)::text)
         ->  Seq Scan on public.equipment_tests et  (cost=0.00..50850.51 rows=1525051 width=160) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: et.id, et.equipment_id, et.test_id, et.equipment_config_id, et.context, et.created_at
         ->  Hash  (cost=49.79..49.79 rows=22 width=134) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=0 loops=1)
               Output: e.id, e.organization_id, e.type, e.model, e.serial_number, e.version, e.calibration_date, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.hw_version
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 0kB
               ->  Index Scan using equip_organization on public.equipments e  (cost=0.42..49.79 rows=22 width=134) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Output: e.id, e.organization_id, e.type, e.model, e.serial_number, e.version, e.calibration_date, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.hw_version
                     Index Cond: ((e.organization_id)::text = '6c93a9b5-cde7-4660-a55a-1ba74b97fc5'::text)
 Total runtime: 0.088 ms
```

**Note that all I did was make the organization_id where parameter one character shorter.**

Our schema:

```
                Table "equipment_tests"
       Column        |            Type             | Modifiers 
---------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id                  | character varying           | not null
 equipment_id        | character varying           | not null
 test_id             | character varying           | not null
 equipment_config_id | character varying           | not null
 created_at          | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "equipment_tests_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "equipment_tests_test_config_context" UNIQUE, btree (test_id, equipment_config_id)
    "equip_tests_equip_id" btree (equipment_id)

                 Table "equipments"
      Column      |            Type             | Modifiers 
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id               | character varying           | not null
 organization_id  | character varying           | not null
 type             | integer                     | 
 model            | character varying           | 
 serial_number    | character varying           | 
 created_at       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at       | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "equipments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "equip_organization" btree (organization_id)
    "equipment_org_model_sn" btree (organization_id, model, serial_number)
```

Generally, the PK's are UUID's, but there is some legacy data where the IDs can be shorter sets of random characters (approx 22 random alphanum characters). Its when we query with these IDs (that are shorter than a UUID), do we find that PG is not using the equipment_id index, and is instead doing a table scan.

The equipment_tests table has roughly 40M rows. The equipments table has roughly 1M rows.

We are using Postgres 9.3.6

We believe this probably has something to do with the fact that the majority of the data in this column is one length, with a minority amount of the data being a shorter length, but I am not sure what that next step in debugging should be?

Comment: Forgot to mention: When the indexes are used, the query takes 200-300ms. When its not used, its closer to 30s.

Comment: Please post the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: First thing I would do is to add bigserials as surrogate keys to both tables, and use that for the FK constraints, and add a unique constraint on the original fat varchar keys. (and similar for `organization_id` which probably is a low-cardinality FK)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I updated the question with analyze,verbose output.

Comment: `Total runtime: 0.088 ms` for the hashed-lookup.

Comment: I thought the first query is the one supposed to be faster?

Comment: @wildplasser, that just avoids the problem... I'd like to understand why varchar is behaving in this manner. Also, thats a fairly significant change you are suggesting.

Comment: The expected vs observer number of rows difference indicates that your statistics are off. Yes: it is a significant change. But it can be done in an hour or so.

Comment: Both statements use an index. The second one where you claim it does not use an index (although it does, just a different one) is a ***lot*** faster than the one that uses the index `equip_tests_equip_id` - and it uses that index because it completely over estimates the number of rows for that step. The second plan (**not** using the index `equip_tests_equip_id`) is the better one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yea, something is not adding up for me. I am fairly certain that one of my original tests was missing the LIMIT, and thus selecting a very large set of rows, and taking ~30s. Re-running the query with the LIMIT has a runtime inline with what the explain is stating. I still dont quite understand why PG is switching the query plan, but I realize its doing something intelligent, and picking the right plan for us. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A query plan based on a hash join is always a good choice (because it is basically O( N+M)) **BUT**: it will fail miserably once the hash table doesn't fit into work memory anymore. (which *could* be caused by -for instance- wrong estimates from the statistics)